# why do I get the out of date message in visual c++ 2010 express

Tags: visual-c++

So I'm starting a book called " Beginning c++ Through Game Programming, third edition, by Michael Dawson" and the very fist program I tried to run didn't work. I even tried just using the source code. Here it is: 
    // Game Over
    // A first C++ program

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Game Over!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume the "out of date" is when you press run? You need to find the build output window that will contain a proper error message. The code is OK but for a VC++ default project you probably need #include "stdafx.h" at the top, or to turn off pre-compiled headers.

Comment: When you say "didn't work", you need to explain exactly what "didn't work" means, including the **exact** text of any error message you're getting. Expecting us to be able to see your screen or read your mind to figure out what the problem might be is a little inconsiderate, when you have the information right at your fingertips (literally - your fingers are on the keyboard when you ask your question). :-)

Comment: Ok I added the code #include "stdafx.h" which got rid of the error but now the window pops up for like a second and then its gone. Also when I try to reopen my project it Doesn't give me the same editing screen as before. Sorry I'm sure these are probaly dumb questions but this is basically the first time I've done programming.

Comment: It's working then, that's normal for a console app to close when finished. Put cin.ignore(); before the return statement and the end and it will wait for you to press enter before ending.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

If this is what you see, just check the checkbox at the bottom and hit "Yes". That will keep it from popping up. It's not an error in your code.

Otherwise, you need to post the error message you are receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Based on various comments I'd made for the default of pre-compiled headers under VC++ and to leave the window open until enter is pressed use the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h" 
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Game Over!" << std::endl;
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think something is wrong with my computer or the (ide, i think that's what that's called) or something like that, because literally nothing is working. Your code above is not working. What are you using to compile and run your code.

Comment: I'm using VS2010 Pro, but am 99% sure there shouldn't be a difference under the Express version. I'm just pressing F5 to run it.